# Websites & Web Application using asp.net mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I was wondering if people could post some examples of interesting websites and web apps that were built with asp.net mvc?

- [Stackoverflow.com](https://stackoverflow.com/) - Programming Q/A
- [Codeplex.com](http://www.codeplex.com/) - Open Source Project Community

and other stackexchangesites... Any others....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mike Bosch has a list of asp.net mvc sites on his blog. http://weblogs.asp.net/mikebosch/archive/2008/05/05/gallery-of-live-asp-net-mvc-sites.aspx